# Decimal format mask in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, format, decimal

In Drupal 7 is it possible to specify an input mask for a decimal so that the value is right justified and comma separated after input has been done?

Comment: Why don't you simple use number_format() php funciton: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Thanks Milan, I have not (yet) done any programming in php since i am very new to the environment (I have been doing Oracle until very recently). I was referring to the default entry of Entity. Is it possible to specify a format so that the capture of a decimal is comma separated and right justified?